# Google Web Font <link> NOT working in E-mail.

Tags: css, email, fonts, phpmailer

I am sending emails by phpmailer and I need to add an external font. I tried 2 ways to add it and no one is working.

1) I tried to use `<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'><meta charset="UTF-8">` in header of my mail. When I read source of email in my Gmail it is something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'><meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body style="background-color: #232227;">
    <div id="content" style="width: 600px; background-color: white; margin: 0 auto; padding-bottom: 20px; border-radius: 5px;margin-top: 50px;">
    <div id="photo" style="width: 600px; height: 300px; background-image: url('https://mywebsite.com/pic/mail.jpg'); background-size: 100% 100%; border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px;"></div>
    <div id="temat" style=style="width: 600px; font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif; color: #232227; font-size: 30px; text-align: center; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px;">Hello<span style="color: #1274FF; font-size: 30px;">!</span></div>
    <div id="tresc" style="width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif; color: #232227; font-size: 16px; text-align: justify;">content</div>
    <a href="https://mywebsite.com" style="text-decoration: none;"><div id="button" style="width: 240px; height: 45px; line-height: 45px; text-decoration: none; margin: 0 auto; background-color: #1274FF; cursor: pointer; font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif; color: white; font-size: 22px; text-align: center; margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom: 30px; border-radius: 5px;">Activate</div></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So looks good but still don't work.

2) I used font-face and effect is same:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>@font-face{
       font-family: 'Titillium Web';
       src: url(https://mywebsite.com/font.ttf);}
</style><meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body style="background-color: #232227;">
    <div id="content" style="width: 600px; background-color: white; margin: 0 auto; padding-bottom: 20px; border-radius: 5px;margin-top: 50px;">
    <div id="photo" style="width: 600px; height: 300px; background-image: url('https://mywebsite.com/pic/mail.jpg'); background-size: 100% 100%; border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px;"></div>
    <div id="temat" style=style="width: 600px; font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif; color: #232227; font-size: 30px; text-align: center; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px;">Hello<span style="color: #1274FF; font-size: 30px;">!</span></div>
    <div id="tresc" style="width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif; color: #232227; font-size: 16px; text-align: justify;">content</div>
    <a href="https://mywebsite.com" style="text-decoration: none;"><div id="button" style="width: 240px; height: 45px; line-height: 45px; text-decoration: none; margin: 0 auto; background-color: #1274FF; cursor: pointer; font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif; color: white; font-size: 22px; text-align: center; margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom: 30px; border-radius: 5px;">Activate</div></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry but I really don't know how to make "code window" from my 2nd code.

Comment: This really does not work well. Client compatibility is very poor. You're better off concentrating on other aspects of your design. And yes, Gmail really is that bad.

Comment: I get lot of newsletters to my gmail and I see in them different fonts :) Maybe there is some list of available fonts? I reall ydon't know what to do with that.

Comment: Yes, there are a bunch of common/standard fonts, but they are not loaded remotely. Do some basic research!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is possible, but email client compatibility is hazy. Additionally, this is a large resource for something like an HTML newsletter (as opposed to a web page, where you can control rendering and loading).

If you really wish to do this, see here for some good information on the subject:

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/will-it-work/webfonts/

Comment: So it is imposible to add font in gmail mail? So in which ways mailchimp and getresponse are working? They use external fonts don't they?

Comment: Yes and I see that only Apple Mail can support it. So I am asking for other methods to add my font to email.

Comment: If the answer was useful to you, I'd appreciate you marking it as accepted. After that, I'd recommend updating the question, which still specifically refers to Google fonts.

Comment: Your answer wasn't helpful. I seen that link before I made that qustion. They say that "Google Web Fonts are the best option available" so I used it and it doesn't work.

Comment: Good luck with your issue.

Comment: Thanks for voting down because you can't solve that problem. Good luck with yourself.